# How can I identify similar documents in R?

Tags: r

At this stage, I am looking for options that can address my problem and so I am hoping to get recommendations from others.  I am sorting through hundreds of documents and would like to reduce manual processing.  The vast majority are form letters and so I would like to identify and group each type of form letter.

The documents are a mix of PDFs, Word, and HTML, and I've been able to extract the text from the PDF documents (haven't attempted Word or HTML yet but should be easy enough).  However, once I get to this stage, I just don't know what I should do next in order to determine, for example, that Document A and Document B are nearly identical except for small changes like the submitter's name and organization.

Comment: **However, once I get to this stage, I just don't know what I should do next.** Are you thinking of an algorithm to do "sentiment analysis", analysis(visualization), recommendation tool? Could you elaborate exactly what it is you would like to do?

Comment: You're looking for "document clustering" approaches. See, for example: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textmineR/vignettes/b_document_clustering.html

Comment: @NelsonGon - Thanks.  I updated the question, but I think edavidaja's suggestion is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @edavidaja - Thanks.  I believe this is what I need.